# To free material from wait block instead of hold and queue when pallet rack has enough space to store

Tags: anylogic

Currently the material get stored if my pallet rack has enough space to store with a hold block (queue.capacity) and a queue. As the process is too long and I don't have enough blocks in my free version (200) I would like to replace the hold block + the queue by a wait block, with boolean hasspace()or something else. Could you help me with the function I need for my wait block to test if my pallet rack has space? Thank you very much.
[part of process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9i6.png)

[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH89c.png)

[rackpick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euusx.png)

[wait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHnhT.png)

Answer (score 0):

on the on enter of wait block:

```
if(palletRack.size()+palletRack.reserved()+rackPick.size()<palletRack.capacity()){

    wait.free(agent);
```

When an agent is picked up from the pallet rack

```
if(wait.size()>0)
    wait.free(wait.get(0));
```

Comment: And how can I avoid the error "There are no empty cells in storage palletRack". I thought  the pallets I can't store when I dont have enough space have to wait in the wait block

Comment: that's what the condition if(palletRack.hasSpace()) does

Comment: Despite the function on the on enter of wait block it releases everything and it comes to the named error :(

Comment: doesn't work, don't know why. I attached the complete process and the properties.. Could you please have a look

Comment: you need to place the code on the on exit of the rackpick, not on the on enter

Comment: ok but doesn't make a difference because the wait block always releases the complete pallets then it comes to the error

Comment: ok, if you think it won't make a difference don't try it and then you can wait for someone else to come and give you my same answer :)

Comment: felipe it doesn't make a difference because I test it and it really doesn't :D

Comment: i replicated your model and it works fine so you probably have another error